# How to switch between predefined material themes?

Tags: angular-material

In Angular Material, we have 4 predefined themes:

- `indigo-pink`
- `pink-bluegrey`
- `purple-green`
- `deeppurple-amber`

I want to include all 4 of them into them app, and provide a switch between them.

**Q:** How can we switch between predefined material themes at run-time?

Note - I do not intend to create any custom theme, I just want to use the predefined ones. It's supposed to be very easy, but I cannot find a single example of doing that.

---

I'm using Angular v16

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer for your question is on the angular material docs itself.
They too use a switcher to switch between themes on the documentation website.
You can just dig up through the documentation website source code, you will surely find the switcher logic somewhere for sure ! Adios

Comment: Very true ! If its present on the website, it might be present in the website source code too

Comment: As in, if you dig long enough, you'll find an answer to everything. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: @vitaly-t i didn't mean to offend !. But, https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/abb2502f3f52133b7dddfa7cdddace0f9a64e129/src/app/shared/theme-picker/theme-picker.ts#L32 here you have it. Take a look at how they have implemented.
One important thing to note is about the view encapsulation